# Checking if file exists on server without using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use a promise with a setInterval function to keep checking to see if a file exists(as it could be still generating on the backend) and then once it is available it runs the renderpage function as shown in my setupFunction(). Currently this program just keeps running until the setInterval maxes out and then it resolves even if the file is there.

```
        async checkFileExist(path, timeout = 20000) {
            let totalTime = 0;
            let checkTime = timeout / 10;
            var self = this;

            return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const timer = setInterval(function () {

                    totalTime += checkTime;

                    let fileExists = self.fileExist(path);

                    if (fileExists || totalTime >= timeout) {
                        alert(totalTime);
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        resolve(fileExists);

                    }
                }, checkTime);
            })
        },
        fileExist(urlToFile) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile, false);
            xhr.send();

            if (xhr.status == "404") {
                alert('false 404 ' + urlToFile)
                return false;
            } else {
                alert('true file found ' + urlToFile)
                return true;
            }
        },
        setupFunction() {
            var self = this
            if (this.filedir == null || this.filedir == "") {
                self.loadingFile = false
            } else {
                this.checkFileExist(this.filedir).then(function (response) {
                    self.loadingFile = false;
                    self.renderPage(this.pageNum);
                }, function (error) {
                    console.error("Failed!", error);
                })
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.setupFunction()
    },
    watch: {
        filedir: function () { // watch it
            this.setupFunction()
        },
    }
```

Comment: You can't know if a file exists without asking the server if it exists

Comment: Why do you even checking if the file exists?

Comment: Because there is a file upload process that uploads some files then on the backend the files are being converted to pdf. So if a user goes to the page ahead of time before the pdf file is available I need to put a placeholder (vue loader/spinner) in front of the area. Atleast that was my idea to make it look more professional.

Comment: Websocket or server-side events would work well here, but making a normal request also shouldn't be that bad.

Comment: I agree. Something must be wrong with my timeout function or FileExists() because it runs until the timeout time then works/resolves.

Answer (score 2):

That won't tell you if a file exists. It will tell you if a URL finds a resource. It's an important distinction since a URL could be handled by server-side code and not a simple static file, while a file might exist and not have a URL.

Making an HTTP request is the simplest way to find out if a URL finds a resource. There are other ways to make HTTP requests (such as the fetch API), but they aren't faster, just different.

A potentially faster (but much more complicated) way would be to use a Websocket. You need to have it open before you wanted to know if the URL exists (otherwise any time savings are lost to establishing the Websocket connection) and you'd need to write the server side code which reacted to the Websocket message by working out if the desired URL existed and telling the client.

Comment: Hey Sorry i have updated it to include my full source code. I accidentally left that first function out. I call this on my components mount.

Comment: The stuff you do around the relevant  code doesn't change the answer.

Comment: This was my first attempt at using a Promise and this request type. I am just not sure why my 2nd alert has such a huge delay from the 1st alert which is immediate on mount().

Comment: What do you mean by *huge*?

Comment: About 20 seconds. So it looks like it is going by my timeout rule. I must have a mistake in my code above or using Promise() incorrectly because it is exactly 20 seconds.

Comment: i dont see my error to be honest.

Comment: For me it looks like you have your backend broken